# How do I determine whether or not a set of vectors (u,v) span a particular solution space Ax=0

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors, linear-transformations, systems-of-equations

Let W be the space to the system solution A**x**=0 and determine whether to set **{u, v}** span W

\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 & -1 & 1\\
0 & 2 & -2 & 2\\
0 & 3 & -3 & 3
\end{bmatrix}

With the vectors

A. **u** = $[1,1,1,0]$ ,  **v** = $[0,-1,0,1]$

B. **u** = $[0,1,1,0]$ ,  **v** = $[1,0,1,1]$

I know that I have to reduce the Matrix to Reduced Row Echelon Form but I don't know where to go from there.

Comment: First row reduce to find the general form of the solution space. Then see if $u, v$ span your solution space, i.e., if you can write your solution space as a linear combination of $u$ and $v$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Matrix $A$ is very simple to reduce to Reduced Row Echelon Form (RREF).  Its RREF is

$\begin{bmatrix} 0 && 1 && - 1 && 1 \\ 0 && 0 && 0 && 0 \\ 0 && 0 && 0 && 0 \end{bmatrix} $

From here, it is clear that the solution to $A x = 0 $ is

We can take $x_1 = t , x_3 = r , x_4 = s $, then $x_2 =  r - s$

Therefore,

$ x = t \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} + r \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} + s \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ -1 \\ 0 \\ 1\end{bmatrix}$

Thus the null space of $A$ is three dimensional, and we need exactly three independent vectors to span it.  Hence, both options for $u, v$ do **not** span the space.

Comment: Shouldn't x_2 be r - s?

Comment: Yes.  You're right.  Thanks.  Corrected.